# hide_empty property not working when using get_terms

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms

I want to display **all** categories including the ones with no posts assigned to it.

So I found out about the 'hide_empty' property. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false
    );
    foreach( get_terms( $args ) as $category ) {
        echo '<p>' . $category->name . '</p>';
    }
 ?>
```

But still only the non-empty categories are shown. What am I missing? My WP version is 4.8.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a plugin that filters your query?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Laxmana](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/40948/laxmana)'s comment above I found the solution. The plugin [User Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/) has a setting in its options to hide empty categories. It is enabled by default. I disabled the option and now all categories are shown.

Thank you for your help, especially thanks to Laxmana!